# Why this simple code can not compile on ios 64 bits?

Tags: delphi

I don't understand why this code can't compile on **ios 64 bits.**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

type
  TRDLVector = record
    case Byte of
      0 : (dw : DWord);
      1 : (bt : array[0..3] of Byte);
    end;

function RdlSubVector(const v : TRDLVector) : TRDLVector;
begin
end;

end.
```

it's return me:

> [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(37): E2581 Backend error: Function return type
>   does not match operand type of return inst!   ret void, !dbg !20074 
>   i64

It's compile ok on delphi 10.1 (berlin) but failed on delphi 10.2 (tokyo)

Is this a bug or I do something wrong ?

**NOTE:** changing `TRDLVector = record` to `TRDLVector = packed record` make it working, don't understand why

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug. Submit a bug report.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Done: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20976 .. I also discover that setting packed record instead of record fix the problem

Comment: @MartynA, no i have 10.2.3 last of the last version (downloaded last week) and don't compile on IOS 64 bit (on other like win32 or ios 32 bit yes it's compile)